# Trouble Installing Ubuntu from DVD and USB

Tags: system-installation

I have no interest in saving anything that is still on this device. 
When I choose "Erase disk and install ubuntu" I receive the error "?????? "??????" Could anyone help me with this problem?

This PC has a 1Tb HD and 4 Gb of RAM
There was previously Windows 7 on the PC, but that is now gone. 
I can let you know anything else about the specs if needed. Thank you.